# xorg-edgers or mamarley ppa?

Tags: nvidia, ppa, nvidia-optimus

I've been having issues (it seems many have been experiencing the same problems) with the NVIDIA drivers and NVIDIA prime lately. More specifically, being unable to switch to the card and getting stuck with a black screen.

I've heard a couple references to a ppa called mamarley having NVIDIA drivers as well that may work better. Can anyone confirm? Are these drivers safe to use?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NVIDIA drivers in my PPA are pretty much the same as the ones in the Xorg Crack Pushers PPA, but sometimes other stuff from that PPA can cause stability problems.  My PPA contains only the drivers, nvidia-settings, and a couple of VDPAU-related packages.  I also tend to be a bit faster getting new versions uploaded than they do.

Comment: Great, thank you for responding. I will swap out my 346 drivers for the ones on your PPA and cross my fingers. I've read comments elsewhere from people who seemed to have luck with this.